# Area formula for parametric surfaces

Tags: analysis

Assume for $\xi\in S^{n-1}$ the parametrization of a closed hypersurface is given by $x(\xi)=R(\xi)\xi\in \mathbb R^n$. Here $R: S^{n-1}\to \mathbb R$ is a positive function. Is there a reference for a proof of the formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
dS_{R}=R^{n-2}\sqrt{R^2+\vert\nabla R(\xi)\vert^2}\:dS_{\xi}\:?
\end{eqnarray*}
Notation: $dS_R$ denotes the area element on $\{R(\xi)\xi:\xi\in S^{n-1}\}$ and $dS_{\xi}$ denotes the area element on $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Can you use riemannian geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{n-1}$ be a local orthonormal frame in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and let $\nabla$ be the gradient in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Thus, in terms of $R$, the metric of $\Sigma:=x(R)$ is given by
$$g_{ij}=\langle\nabla_iX,\nabla_jX\rangle=R^2\delta_{ij}+\nabla_iR\nabla_jR,$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The volume element is given by
\begin{equation}\label{elementodevolume}
dV_g=R^{n-1}\sqrt{1+\frac{|\nabla R|^2}{R^2}}=R^{n-2}\sqrt{R^2+|\nabla R|^2}.
\end{equation}
Let's proof the previous term:
Observe that for an invertible square matrix $A$ and $u,v$ column vectors, the  $\textit{matrix determinat lemma}$ states
$$\mbox{det}(A+uv^T)=(1+v^TA^{-1}u)\mbox{det}A.$$
In particular, for $A=I$ and $u=v=\nabla\rho$, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
dV_g&=&\sqrt{\mbox{det}(g_{ij})}\\
    &=&\sqrt{\mbox{det}\left(R^2\left(\delta_{ij}+\frac{\nabla_iR\nabla_jR}{R^2}\right)\right)}\\
    &=&\sqrt{R^{2(n-1)}\mbox{det}\left(\delta_{ij}+\frac{\nabla_iR\nabla_jR}{R^2}\right)}\\
    &=&R^{n-1}\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{|\nabla R|^2}{R^2}\right)\mbox{det}(\delta_{ij})}\\
    &=&R^{n-1}\sqrt{1+\frac{|\nabla R|^2}{R^2}}
    =R^{n-2}\sqrt{R^2+|\nabla R|^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Many thanks, that is very helpful indeed ! I didn't know about the"matrix determinant lemma".